# "...hat Philosophie, Pädagogik, Theaterwissenschaften, Anthropologie und Politik studiert"

Tags: meaning

Ich denke, es ist einigen von euch auch schon aufgefallen, dass manche Leute in ihrer Biographie auf einer Webseite oder Beschreibung ihres Werdegangs durch Dritte bei einem Interview so vorgestellt werden, um ihre Expertise anzugeben.

Impliziert dieser Satz eigentlich für euch im deutschen Sprachgebrauch, dass entsprechende Person auch einen Hochschulabschluss gemacht hat? Denn bei genauem Nachforschen findet man dann doch heraus, dass der ein oder andere 20 Semester studiert hat ohne einen Abschluss bzw. in einem Fach mal immatrikuliert war.

Mir ist schon klar, dass v.a. bei den geisteswissenschaftlichen Magisterstudiengängen mehrere Fächer parallel belegt werden. Ich finde es nur etwas merkwürdig, dass Naturwissenschaftler eigentlich immer angeben, worin sie einen Abschluss haben (Dipl. Mathematiker/Biologe), bei den Geistes- und Sozialwissenschaftlern **scheinbar** aber eher aufgezählt wird, was man mal studiert hat. Zumal wenn dann im Werdegang auf einer Webseite nur aufgezählt wird, was studiert wurde, ich aber keine formale Abschlussbezeichnung finde, weiss ich ehrlich gesagt nicht, was ich jetzt annehmen soll, je mehr Studiengänge dann aufgezählt werden, desto mehr tendiere ich persönlich dazu anzunehmen, dass gar kein Abschluss gemacht wurde.

Comment: ...udn was hat das jetzt mit GL&U zu tun?

Comment: @Takkat Ich seh dass nicht in der Art und Ausmass im englischen Lebensläufen/Blogseiten z.B. Da wird eher genau aufgelistet wo man Abschluss und wirklich erwiesene Qualifikation hat (auch weil man einen Bachelor bekommt nach schon 3 Jahren, in D zählte dann eben hptsl. Diplom/Magister, bis dahin schaffen es aber nicht alle) Und v.a. bei Geisteswiss. scheint es eher **sprachlicher Usus** zu sein, aufzulisten was alles studiert wurde statt dem konkreten Abschluss, selbst wenn dieser erzielt wurde.

Comment: Kein *Fragezeichen*! Was ist deine Frage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gerade wenn man auf [Magister](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magister) studiert(e), hat man als Abschluss einen *Magister Artium*. Daraus lässt sich nicht ablesen, was man eigentlich studiert hat. Deshalb bietet sich an, zu sagen, welche Studienfachkombination man studierte.

Bei Naturwissenschaften ist eher ersichtlich, welches Fach man studierte. D. h., dort sagt man eher 'Ich bin Mathematiker mit Schwerpunkt …'.

Comment: wie schon bei user kommentiert, früher macht das evtl. noch Sinn, auch wenn hier nicht mal annäherend eine wirkliche  Gleichgewichtung der Themen vorzufinden war wie es obige Sprechweise suggeriert. Imho verschlimmbessert diese Formulierung bei jüngeren Leuten wie mir nur den Eindruck vom Know-how entspr. Person anstatt schönzufärben, von daher empfind ich den Gebrauch im persönl. Werdegang auf einer Homepage recht unglücklich. Auf einer Webseite ist doch genug Platz um zu schreiben, was Hauptfach und Nebenfächer waren :) Man sagt doch auch Mag. in Philosophie oder Dipl. Mathematiker?!

Answer (score 4):

Das scheint ein alter Brauch im deutschen Sprachgebiet zu sein.
Hier das  Klagelied eines bekannten Wissenschaftlers aus dem neunzehnten Jahrhundert:

> Habe nun, ach! Philosophie,
>   Juristerei und Medizin,
>   Und leider auch Theologie!
>   Durchaus studiert, mit heißem Bemühn.
>   Da steh’ ich nun, ich armer Tor!
>   Und bin so klug als wie zuvor

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde unabhängig von der Anzahl annehmen, dass kein Abschluss vorliegt. Wenn man bei einem Werdegang mit Kenntnissen beeindrucken will, dann gelingt dies natürlich umso besser, wenn man einen Abschluss hat, und dann gibt es keinen Grund ein entsprechendes Studium zu erwähnen, aber Abschlüsse bescheiden zu verschweigen.

Gerade wenn den Leser die Frage, ob ein Abschluss vorliegt, interessieren könnte, wäre es ja geradezu unhöflich, den Leser auf weitere Suche zu schicken. Wo sonst soll er nach den Abschlüssen fahnden?

Also ist es wohl Schönfärberei.

Dass derjenige aber selbständig dazuschreibt 'gescheitert/abgebrochen' wäre etwas viel verlangt.

Comment: Komisch ist ja, dass manche trotzdem diese Formulierung im Werdegang auf einer Webseite benutzen, obwohl sie einen Abschluss haben, um sich als Multi-Gelehrter darzustellen oder was weiss ich nicht alles. Ich kenne jetzt die Studienordnungen von Magisterstudiengängen nicht en detail und weiss nicht wie stark Teilfächer gewichtet sind, aber man ist ja immer noch für z.B. Philosophie immatrikuliert und muss den Grossteil der Scheine hier absolvieren. Doppel- und Dreifachstudium wie es obige Schreibweise suggeriert kenn ich wenige, die das erfolgreich überstanden haben. Eher kontraproduktive

Comment: Formulierung für mich

Comment: Eine empirische Untersuchung liegt mir nicht vor. Oft gibt es ja Nebenfächer - z.B. konnte man Soziologie mit den Nebenfächern Philosophie, Psychologie, Volkswirtschaft und einigen mehr studieren. Wenn man hier nur einen Abschluss im Hauptfach macht, dann würde man ja diesen i.d.R. erwähnen. Wenn man keinen Abschluss erwähnt - woher weißt Du dann, dass die Personen einen oder mehrere Abschlüsse haben?

Comment: Gibt ja noch andere Quellen... Vielleicht war das in den 50ern noch mehr Usus aufzulisten was man studiert hatte, es ist ja in den letzten 60 Jahren enorm viel Wissen dazugekommen. Heute kann keiner sagen, er hat Informatik, Biologie, Physik studiert und auf allen Gebieten umfassendes Wissen und Überblick. Widerspruch in sich. Philosophie, Psychologie, VWL sind auch RIESEN Gebiete mit eigener Methodik. Man sieht es v.a. oft bei Intellektuellen oder Journalisten, die keinen Abschluss haben und dann sehr schönfärben mit dieser Ausdrucksweise, ohne das man jetzt einen Schluss auf die Expertise

Comment: ziehen könnte. Dein Kommentar erinnert mich an sehr alten Lehrer auf dem Gymnasium, der 5 Fächer unterrichtete, alles Geistes- ound Sozialwissenschaften. Wahrscheinlich war das früher in den Disziplinen wirklich noch gängiger und mehr gerechtfertigt, weil Stoff noch nicht so dicht und ausdiff. wie heute in einzelnen Studiengängen. Aber das sollte sich mit eingeführten Bachelor und Verschulung jetzt ändern...

Answer (score 3):

Die Beurteilung ist vom Kontext abhängig. In einem formalen Lebenslauf steht immer auch das Abschlussdatum, sodass die obengenannte Formulierung ganz klar dazu dient, zu erklären, dass man die besagten Jahre nicht mit Däumchendrehen oder Gefängnis verbracht hat, sondern mit Studieren.

Wenn mir jemand mit dem Satz vorgestellt wird (für ein oder zwei Studien, nicht für fünf), dann würde ich schon von einem Abschluss ausgehen.

Auf einer Webseite würde ich je nach Kontext nicht mal davon ausgehen, dass derjenige jemals in einer Uni war.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke, es kommt zunächst einmal darauf an, wie man selber "studieren" versteht.

- Früher hieß studieren, dass man zuerst einmal Philosophie studiert hat, um dann anschließend auf das Studienfach zu wechseln, das man studieren wollte (Mathematik, Physik, Biologie, Jura, Medizin, …). Hierbei wurde studieren in erster Linie als Persönlichkeitsbildung angesehen und konnte auch länger dauern. Daher war man auch relativ frei in der Kombination der Fächer, die man studierte, und hat oftmals auch Sachen nur aus Interesse gehört.
- Heute heißt studieren etwas anders, die Philosophie ist mehr oder weniger verpönt, und es geht mehr darum (nach dem Diktat der Wirtschaft) Fachidioten in möglichst kurzer Zeit zu produzieren. Da bleibt die Allgemein- und Persönlichkeitsbildung leider auf der Strecke (nun merkt die Wirtschaft, dass ein Bachelor wohl nicht das kann, was die Wirtschaft braucht). Heute wird nur noch gelernt, was ETCS-Punkte bringt. Leider.

Auf Bewerbungen (und auch entsprechende Webseiten) hatte das den Einfluss, dass

- nach altem Verständnis die Entwicklung der Persönlichkeitsbildung klar dargestellt werden musste (und es nicht so wichtig war, welcher Abschluss erreicht wurde).
- nach neuem Verständnis es in erster Linie auf einen standardisierten Berufsnamen (sagt nicht unbedingt etwas über die Ausbildung aus!), die Art des Abschlusses, die Note und die Schnelligkeit des Studiums ankommt, die Persönlichkeitsbildung aber vollkommen vernachlässigt wird. Daher ist in einer Bewerbung ein tabellarischer Lebenslauf mit klaren Fakten erwünscht. Unter dieser Voraussetzung gilt: Steht ein Abschluss nicht da, wurde er schlicht nicht gemacht. Oftmals wird dann statt des Diploms das Vordiplom angegeben. Oder es wird aus Taktik gezielt eine Lücke gelassen, um neugierig auf den Kandidaten zu machen und diesem so ein Bewerbungsgespräch zu verschaffen.

Ein Studium der Geisteswissenschaften stellt nach meinem Verständnis auch heute noch eher eine Persönlichkeitsbildung dar, daher auch der andere Stil bei den Bewerbungen/Webseiten.

Hintergrund dieses Verständnisses: u. a. von mir gehaltene Bewerbungstrainings und Rückmeldungen von Studenten.